# Functional Programming: modify EdgeList based on condition

Tags: graphs-and-networks, functional-style

I have a simple functional programming question: I have a simple `EdgeList` defined in Mathematica, I would like to modify the value of certain element of the list based on a condition.
I see how to define the conditional `If`, but I don't know how to "scan" my `EdgeList` and modify the elements so that it returns another `EdgeList`.
Could someone show me a simple example on how to accomplish this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: You could try some Rule-based approach `{a \[UndirectedEdge] b, b \[UndirectedEdge] c, c \[UndirectedEdge] a} /. a \[UndirectedEdge] x_ :> a \[UndirectedEdge] y`

Comment: @ssch Thanks for the input, however I cannot use a rule-based approach because I need to call a function behind the rules. And, as far as I know, when you apply the rule it will only call the function once for every edges matching the rule. In fact, what I want to do is to rename some edge: every edge with name "ABC" will become "ABC 1", "ABC 2", ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First a list of `UndirectedEdge`

```
list = MapIndexed[UndirectedEdge[First[#2], #1] &, CharacterRange["a", "e"]]
```

Let's say you want to change all edges where the head is `OddQ` then you could do something like

```
list /. e : UndirectedEdge[a_, b_] :> If[OddQ[a], UndirectedEdge[a, b <> "1"], e]
```

The trick is to apply the rule to all edges but only change those which match your `If` condition. Maybe a bit clear is to use `Map` and first define a function which modifies exactly one `UndirectedEdge`

```
f[e : UndirectedEdge[a_, b_]] :=  If[OddQ[a], UndirectedEdge[a, b <> "1"], e]
f /@ list
```

There are many more ways and the more experienced users will probably use such a map with a pure `Function` where you don't have to define `f` separately.

### Update for increasing numbers

To `Map` a function usually modifies every element of a list but the function itself only works on the data without knowing how many elements it has processed or other global things. To stick with `Map` we have to introduce some (at least locally defined) global variable which counts. I will use `i` here which is increased every time a the edge was modified. Additionally, I define the `Function` for modifying an edge *in-place* with `Function` and `e` is the edge-parameter:

```
Block[{i = 1},
 Function[e, 
   If[OddQ[First[e]], UndirectedEdge[First[e], Last[e] <> ToString[i++]], e]] /@ list
 ]
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks a lot :) if I may, just a little "side question", I see that in your example you append "1" to the edge value, how would you attempt to rewrite f so that it increments the number every time it's called? (a1, a2, ...) this is a problem I am facing at the moment...